# Azure Created Container Not Displayed in Portal

Tags: azure, azureportal, azure-cli

I'm following steps in this tutorial: [How to use Blob storage from iOS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-ios-how-to-use-blob-storage/) to generate Shared Access Signatures (SAS). I ran the commands successfully including this one:

> azure storage container sas create --container sascontainer
>   --permissions rw --expiry 2016-09-05T00:00:00

My terminal said:

> info:    Executing command storage container sas create
>   + Creating shared access signature for container sascontainer

I looked at azure portal and I don't see that container: sascontainer created anywhere. According to this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-command-line-tools/) (my understanding) is that it will create a container:
--container : The name of the storage container to create.

So, where is it!? Shouldn't that command be enough to create that container and make it visible in my azure portal!? I also have looked in Azure Classic Portal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> azure storage container sas create --container sascontainer
>   --permissions rw --expiry 2016-09-05T00:00:00

This command will not create a blob container. It will create a Shared Access Signature on a container named `sascontainer` with `Read` and `Write` permission that will expire on `2016-09-05T00:00:00`.

To create a blob container, the command you want to use is:

```
azure storage container create "sascontainer"
```

Once this command completes successfully, you should be able to see the blob container in the portal.